# I want to print Table data into Textarea in java

Tags: java

In java i want to print jTable(Table) data into Textarea("AREA" in My code) ,But when i run this code which is given below it does not print all row and column data in text area and showing a message in output that

**Error in OUTPUT Is**

"  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')  "

**Code Which I used**

```
DefaultTableModel model1  = (DefaultTableModel) BILL_table.getModel();
int nRow = model1.getRowCount(), nCol = model1.getColumnCount();
Object [][] tableData = new Object [nRow][nCol];
for(int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
{ 
   for(int j = 0 ; j< nCol ; j++)
   {
   tableData[i][j] = model1.getValueAt(i, j);
   AREA.append ((String) tableData [i][j] + "\t");

   }
   AREA.append("\n");
}
```

[Data In My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPGm8.png)

[Output printed in my AREA (textarea)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS0jv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably here:

```
AREA.append ((String) tableData [i][j] + "\t");
```

It seems `tableData[i][j]` is an instance of `Integer` (a number) which can of course not be cast to a string. The correct thing to do is to *convert* it to a string:

```
AREA.append (tableData[i][j].toString() + "\t");
```

Note that you don't even have to do that explictly since that conversion will happen automatically whenever you concatenate an object with a string. So you can just write

```
AREA.append (tableData[i][j] + "\t");
```

The latter will work even if the `tableData[i][j]` happens to be `null` (the former will throw a `NullPointerException` in that case).